# Laravel 7 DB Query only where date range not in date range

Tags: php, sql

I have something like this:

```
$from = min($start_date, $end_date);
$till = max($start_date, $end_date);

DB::table('booked')
     ->where('start', '<=', $from)
     ->where('end', '>=', $till)
     ->get();
```

This is a nice solution form stackoverflow.

It seems works, but I need the opposite.

In my DB I have this data: start: 2020-09-27 10:00:00  end: 2020-09-27 12:00:00
I have to query that rows where for example:

$start_date(2020-09-27 9:00:00) and $end_date(2020-09-27 11:00:00) where both not in start: and end: Hopefully my question is clear enough.

Comment: your end_date `2020-09-27 11:00:00` is between the given range and your telling in opposite way

Comment: Yes this is the point, if it is between the given range then I don't want it in the result. Only if not in the given range.

Comment: so it would be like, if any parameter start or end date is between given date range, you don't want to include

Comment: Yes exactly, just the given date range is stored in the db, and the other range is variable. So I would like to check that the variable is not in the stored range.

Comment: Just to be clear. Let's say data in db are `start - 10, end = 12` and now if input range is `start = 8, end = 9` => yes, `start = 9, end = 11` => no, `start = 11, end = 11:30` => no, `start = 11, end = 13` => no, `start = 13, end = 14` = yes. If that so, will give you a query

Comment: Yes this is what I would like to solve.

Comment: ahappydev already gave the answer. I am late, so i'll skip for now.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting you right this is what you need

```
$from = min($start_date, $end_date);
$till = max($start_date, $end_date);

DB::table('booked')
     ->where('start', '>=', $till)
     ->orWhere('end', '<=', $from)
     ->get();
```

Comment: It assumes you have correct(logically) data in database.

Comment: Hmm, this is great! Thank you very much, I just work on this on the last 2 hours and I can't understand why not working properly! (Probably I need some rest) Cheers!

Comment: This is really works well, but I have a problem. If I have more date in the database then it not working anymore, any idea?

Comment: What you mean by "more date"? What is not working? Please, describe.